# Shifter Power Method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

If we know all the eigenvalues of a matrix A except the largest one. We want to apply shifted power iteration to get the largest eigenvalue. Something like $(A-\alpha I)$ . Then what should be the value of shift ($\alpha$) to make it converge as fast as possible ?

Answer (score 1):

If the eigenvalues of $A$ are all real:

$$\lambda_1 \gt \lambda_2 \gt \ldots \gt \lambda_k$$

then the power iterations of the shifted matrix $A - \alpha I$ converge at the optimal rate when $\alpha = \frac{\lambda_2 + \lambda_k}{2}$.

Something similar can be done if the eigenvalues are complex but known except for the one of greatest modulus.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention about the real eigenvalues. So for shifted power method we can say convergence will happen at the rate of $\mod(\frac{\lambda_2 - \alpha}{\lambda_1 - \alpha})$. Which means we want to make $\alpha$ as close as possible to $\lambda_2$. And above condition will ensure that.

Is the understanding correct ?

Comment: You want to put $\alpha$ halfway between $\lambda_2$ and the eigenvalue at the other end of the spectrum, which I labelled $\lambda_k$.  If you put $\alpha$ any closer to $\lambda_2$, then the shifted other end of the spectrum $\lambda_k - \alpha$ starts to get bigger (in absolute value) than $\lambda_2 - \alpha$.

Comment: Yes. got that.. Thanks a lot.